# How to assign value to array with a key array?

Tags: php

I have a value.

```
$v = "Foo";
```

and i have an array to store my data

```
$array = array();
```

and I have an array of "keywords"

```
$k = array("bla", "fas");
```

I want :

```
$array = array(
    "bla" => array(
         "fas" => $v
     )
)
```

I've tryed this :

```
$array = array();

$v = "bla";

$k = array("a", "b");

$str = "[" . implode("][", $k) . "]";

// $array[$k] = $v;
// $array{$k} = $v;
// $array{$str} = $v;
${$array.$str} = $v;

print_r($array);
```

So, the question is : How to assign value to array with a key array?

Comment: You cannot traverse multiple levels of an array using varvar syntax. This requires a cumbersome recursive function with references, or -if versed enough- the guts to utilize what separates scripting from compiled languages: `eval`.

Comment: ho, thanks mario, english is my 2nd language, i wouldn't had found that. It's indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$v = "Foo";
$array = array();
$k = array();
$k["fas"] = $v;
$array["bla"] = $k
```

Comment: The whole point was to have a dynamic way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you're looking for this

```
$num = count($k);
$array = array($k[$num-1]=>$v);
for($i=$num-2;$i>=0;$i--){
  $array = array($k[$i]=>$array);  
}
```

Comment: so simple i like it. thanks

Comment: There's a delay. don't worry about it.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't it. found the answer into mario's link. i can't accept an answer and mislead someone else.

Comment: I'm quite sure this one is better than that one. At least that one is more complex than this one (unnecessary recursive function). After all, I don't think people would be mislead ed :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array($k[0] => array($k[1] => $v));
```

It is dynamic because it uses only the input variables provided and it produces the output you described.

Answer (score -1):

init:

```
$twodimensionaLArray = array ( "foo" => array("bar", "fomb") );
```

getting value

```
$subarr = $twodimensionaLArray['foo']; // gives array("bar", "fomb")
```

getting element of subarray

```
$elem = $subarr[1]; //  gives "fomb"
```

etc . etc.